# Как реализовать отправку команды со страницы на Django по SSH?

Tags: python, django, ssh

Вопрос по поводу реализации отправки SSH со страницы в Django. Необходимо, чтобы При нажатии кнопки отправлялась команда по SSH на сервер.
Есть такой код с использованием Paramiko:

views.py

```
class StartServer(Server, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AddServerForm(request.POST or None)
        servers = Server.objects.all()
        context = {'form': form, 'csservers': servers}
        return render(request, 'csservers/server_detail.html', context)

    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     pass

    def start_server(self, request, pk):
        print(request.POST)
        if request.POST:
            server = Server.objects.get(id=pk)
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(hostname=server.host, username=server.server_username, password=server.secret, port=server.port)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./<команда>')
            data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
            client.close()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{ server.host }}
    {{ server.port }}
    {{ server.server_username }}
    {{ server.secret }}

    <form action="{% url 'server_start' server.slug server.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" style="outline: none; border: none; background-color: red; color: #fff;">Запустить сервер</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Если нажимаю на кнопку, то выдает ошибку 405. Мне нужно, чтобы на локальную машину с Ubuntu по SSH происходило подключение и отправлялась команда ./<комада>.
Возможно ли как-то более логично и локанично реализовать данную идею или возможно при помощи Paramiko все же это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось реализовать то, что хотел.
В итоге получилось сделать вот так:
**views.py**

```
class StartServer(Server, View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AddServerForm(request.POST or None)
    servers = Server.objects.all()
    context = {'form': form, 'csservers': servers}
    return render(request, 'csservers/server_detail.html', context)

def post(self, request, pk):
    server = Server.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.POST:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hostname=server.host, username=server.server_username, password=server.secret,
                       port=server.port)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./csgoserver st')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        client.close()
        return redirect(server.get_absolute_url())
    return redirect(server.get_absolute_url())
```

**HTML**:

```
<form action="{% url 'server_start' server.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" style="outline: none; border: none; background-color: red; color: #fff;">Запустить сервер</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('servers', ServerListView.as_view(), name='servers'),
path('servers/<slug:slug>', ServerDetailView.as_view(), name='servers_detail'),
path('servers_add/', AddServer.as_view(), name='server_add'),
path('server_start/<int:pk>', StartServer.as_view(), name='server_start'),
```

]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поправил ответ, содержащий только информацию к вопросу и ответ на него, который нашел сам =)